# divs height dependant in remaining space

Tags: html, css, layout

example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top">
    </div>
    <div id="mid">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VTNxe/

i want the green div to be under the yellow one, and his height should be always that high to exactly fill the parent div.
exampke: parent-height:300 & yellow height:100 => green-height:200
or     : parent-height:350 & yellow height:50 => green-height:300

this should even be if the yellows or the green height is changed dureing runtime with javascript for example.
is it possible to archieve this only with css?

thx

Comment: What is the real situation?  Is there content in these boxes, etc.?  Both posted answers thus far hide part of the green box.  It is unclear from the question if this is allowable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with pixels, I think this is the closest you can get with only css:

```
#mid{
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    width:100%;
    top:100px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/VTNxe/4/

Note that I set the `top` property the same as the height of the `#top` div. This means that the height of #top has to be fixed. As you state in your question, you might want to change this height with javascript or something. Perhaps you could consider changing the top at the same time then?

Comment: this, it seems that this is the solution i was looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/VTNxe/1/

Play a bit around with `position:absolute;`: the #top div is always fixed size at the same place. and then use a `height: 100%` for the #mid div.

```
#parent{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}

#top{
    position:absolute;
    background:yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 1; /* necessary, else the #mid would lay over it */
}

#mid{
    background:green;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not make the height of `mid` equal the parent height minus `top`.  It just overlays `top` on top of `mid` potentially covering up content in `mid`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne does this make any difference? the result would be the same?

Comment: The result is the same in this very simplistic case.  But most of the time these sort of questions are simplified versions of the real question.  If `mid` is anything at all other than a solid color then it makes a difference.  It depends on the real situation which was not provided.  Not saying your answer is wrong, just pointing that out in case the real situation differs from a solid color.

Comment: @JamesMontagne you show me a simple case; I answer you how to solve this simple case easily. Or be please more precise in your question.

Comment: I have asked no question.  I simply pointed out a potential shortcoming of this approach.  It is up to the person who did ask the question (user2304753) to decide if this is a problem in his real situation or not.  I am simply pointing it out.

Comment: @JamesMontagne you are right. the green one is too big, we just can see it because its compeltely green.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is yes, it is possible to do with just CSS. One way might be to make the green box with a height:100%; and do overflow:hidden; in the parent div. Then changing the height of the yellow will make it look like they vary proportionally.

Comment: but then the green one would be too big, you just cant see it